# French and Chinese characters are not appearing correctly

Tags: java, utf-8, io, character-encoding

I have internationalization support in my App.
The issue is in displaying the literals on UI.
e.g I have a Chinese literal in my code as 
不安全密码！
However on browser , the field is shown as 
ä¸å®å¨å¯ç ï¼

similarly in french langauge, a literal 
"Très faible" gets displayed as "Trï¿½s faible"

Appreciate your help..Thanks

Comment: What kind of application is it? Web? Swing? Mobile? Other?

Comment: Where do you want to display

Comment: Check your encoding. Use UTF-8 if possible.

Comment: you can force text encoding in your browser, check UTF-8 when displaying french language and Big5 for chinese then make sure you send a response type with the encoding from the server so your users do not have to make this change

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the bytes rendered as ISO-8859-1 or similar.

Try setting charset in content-type `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");`, include appropriate meta-tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

What are you using to generate that page?

Comment: This is a web App.The issue does not seem to be of UTF-8 because that is already in place.However it seems to be a server side issue. e.g 不安全密码！literal is in my properties file. when I do maven clean install and in the target folder .jar , if I open the properties file , the literal is shown as  ä¸å®å¨å¯ç ï¼,  which is what gets displayed on browser.

Comment: Ah. Did you encode your properties with utf8toascii ?

Comment: I am writing the property file as :   BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(propFile, true));
properties.store(out, null);

Comment: The statement “All Strings in Java are UTF-8” is false.  There are a few ways that can be interpreted, but none of them will make that sentence true.

Comment: @Aadil: and your properties file shows these strange characters? Which editor didi you open that with? As you see 2 strange chars per one french you might just use editor not capable of utf-8?